# Loadfactor on Scala HashMap

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, hashmap

Scala's HashMaps opposed to Java's do not offer to change the load factor.
If I am using `Integer`s as keys, will it use a load factor of 1?

I am aware that I could just implement a List and fill it with nulls and the elements, but
a map is much more convinient.

What is the default load factor of `HashMap`s in Scala with `Integer` keys?

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap`, the default load factor [seems to be 0.75](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/28eef15f3cc46f6d3dd1884e94329d7601dc20ee/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.scala#L615) and I don't see anything specific to ints. You can also set a custom load factor [using a builder](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap$.html#newBuilder%5BK,V%5D(initialCapacity:Int,loadFactor:Double):scala.collection.mutable.Builder%5B(K,V),scala.collection.mutable.HashMap%5BK,V%5D%5D).

However, the story is different for immutable collections. Since they do not change, there shouldn't be a need of a load factor as the whole map needs to be recreated when an element is "added".
That being said, I don't see any kind of load factor when inspecting the [code of `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala#L465).

If you create the `HashMap` with specific functions (not offering the ability for setting custom load factors), it [seems like it is dynamically calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063614/10871900).

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not a subject matter expert in Scala.